# What's an early modern English excalmation roughly meaning "raise the roof!"?

Tags: idioms, translation, literature, early-modern-english, exclamations

I am a translator of Russian historical fiction set in the early modern period (mid-late 16th century) and I am looking for some good period-specific English equivalents of the phrase "жги-говори!" (literally, "burn-speak!"), a phrase shouted at a party to egg on revelers and especially those dancing and singing.

In modern speech, it's like saying "raise the roof!" or "let's get down!" or (in the context of dj-ing) "more fire!" But what's something an English speaker in the 16th century might have called out in a moment of great excitement at a raucous feast? I don't need total historical accuracy, but I want something evocative and plausible.

Comment: *Wassail* - no citations, look it up in a dictionary and decide for yourself if it (a) amuses you to use the word and (b) is not anachronistic.

Comment: ["Tonight we're gonna party like it's 1699"?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amish_Paradise) ;-) In seriousness, I'm not sure there's going to be a 1-to-1 correlation—an exclamation that is not only a call to drink, but to encourage dancers or singers. Off the top of my head, thinking of Shakespearean dialog, all I can think of is lines that "start the party": "Strike up, pipers," "Come, let's have a dance," etc.

Comment: "Pile more hay up there!"

Comment: "Let us make merry, lads and lasses!"

Comment: exclamation, please. :)

Comment: Get down and galliard!

Answer (score 3):

### [Eat, drink, and be merry!](https://grammarist.com/proverb/eat-drink-and-be-merry/)

Sometimes followed by "for tomorrow we die!"

The meaning is clear, plus it's an expression that modern readers will likely have heard before. Being a reference to the Bible, it feels appropriate for the time period, plus it was really [used in EModE](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A26129.0001.001/1:1.1?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=And%20Be%20merry).

Comment: I remember when Dairy Queen adopted this as an ad slogan.  They dropped it like a hot potato when they realized the rest of the phrase was "for tomorrow we die."